# Inverting differential equation using finite element methods

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method

tl;dr; How to use FEM tools to extract models needed to invert PDEs.

**Context**

In astrophysics, one is interested in so-called 'cosmic archeology' which involves recovering the origin of a given observation, while modelling its evolution. The idea is to be able to understand what may have caused in the past an given signature found in  the data. For instance, can we explain the observed vertical velocity distribution of stars above and below the galactic disc seen by the Gaia spacecraft in terms of past satellites having hit our Milky way.

[image: Gaia Image of our milky way]

**Example**

As a test example let us consider a 1D diffusion equation sourced by a finite set of heat sources

```
 source[x_, t_] = 
 3 BSplineBasis[3, t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4] +
   2 BSplineBasis[3, -2 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 5/8) 4] +
   BSplineBasis[3, -1 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 2/8) 4] +
   BSplineBasis[3, -1 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4] +
   BSplineBasis[3, -1/2 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 4/8) 4] +
   3/2 BSplineBasis[3, -3 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4];

ContourPlot[source[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 36, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Contours -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The diffusion diagram will obey

```
    sol0 = NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, t], t] - 1/4 D[f[x, t], x, x] == 
        source[x, t],
       f[x, 0] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}];

     ContourPlot[sol0[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {x, t}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All, Contours -> 30, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here I have assumed arbitrarily that the edges of [0,1] did not let heat diffuse.
I also assumed that initially there was no heat.

Let me first  generate the corresponding data set of positing and time $(x,t)$ for later use

```
data = N[Flatten[
Table[{x, t, sol0[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/32}, {t, 0, 1, 1/32}], 1]];
```

My purpose is to [invert](http://www.ipgp.fr/~tarantola/Files/Professional/Books/InverseProblemTheory.pdf) this data set to recover the source of heating.

> I other words, can I  **recover the first plot from the second one**, if I assume 
>   I know how the heat source diffuse?

**Attempt**

I can define a set of spline functions which cover the $(x,t)$ space as follow:

```
nn = 16;
knots = Flatten[{{0, 0}, (Range[0, nn]/nn), {1, 1}}];

basis0 = Flatten@
   Table[BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, 
      t], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];
```

For instance, the 60th function obeys:

```
Plot3D[basis0[[60]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The image of this basis satisfies

```
basis = Flatten@
   Table[NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, t], t] - 1/4 D[f[x, t], x, x] == 
       BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, t],
      f[x, 0] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, 
     f[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];

Plot3D[basis[[60]], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From this basis and the data I can generate the linear model `a0` and `a` relating resp. the spline coefficients to the source map and the spline coefficients heat map:

```
ff = Function[{x, t}, basis0 // Evaluate];
a0 = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data0);
```

and

```
ff = Function[{x, t}, basis // Evaluate];
a = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data);
a // Image // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let me first check that I can fit the source map with the splines:

```
fit0[x_, t_] = 
basis0.LinearSolve[Transpose[a0].a0, Transpose[a0].(Last /@ data0)];
ContourPlot[fit0[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly, I can define an (isotropic) penalty corresponding to $\int |\Delta T|^2 dx dt$ as

```
ff = Function[{x, t}, D[basis0, x, x] + D[basis0, t, t] // Evaluate];
s0 = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data0);
pen = Transpose[s0].s0; pen /= Max[Flatten[Abs[pen]]];
pen // Image // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A solution to the inverse problem then follows simply from inverting `a` with a small [roughness](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10997/1089) penalty as

```
sol[x_, t_] = 
  basis0.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a + 10^-7 pen, 
    Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)];

ContourPlot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

I am fairly certain my present implementation is effectively redundant with the way `NDSolve` can actually solves the differential equation using Finite Element methods. Hence my question:

> Could one make use of the actual solver in `NDSolve` to formulate the inverse problem?

In other words, can we extract from the FEM toolkit `FEM_a`,`FEM_source` and `FEM_solution` and `FEM_grid` so that

```
   FEM_solution =  FEM_a  FEM_source
```

where 'FEM_' stands for as sampled by the underlying mesh,`FEM_grid` of the FEM toolkit.

This would be of interest in terms of efficiency, but also in order to address more complex and  realistic [inverse problems](http://www.ipgp.jussieu.fr/%7Etarantola/Files/Professional/Teaching/Diverse/NaturePhysics/NaturePhysicsTarantola.pdf)?

For Gaia data, the diffusion is in fact occurring in 3D and is anisotropic,
so a robust and efficient formulation would help!

Technically I believe [FEM](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#788882543) have access to both `a` and `pen` so it would be great to be able to access them  for the sake of solving the inverse problem.

I am guessing that [this link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#788882543) would be a good starting point?

**Comment**

Note that the above implementation is partially incorrect at the top edge, because most spline basis elements are  required to be zero on the boundary, whereas the correct solution should have an outgoing flux condition. This is something the FEM  would handle naturally when the boundary conditions are taken care of.

```
  Plot[{sol[x, 1], sol0[x, 1]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that in astronomy we unfortunately don't have access to the full diffusion diagram but only typically to a given snapshot (i.e. data on a line at fixed time, and/or possibly the time derivative on that line). So we can only extrapolate in the past up to some quite limited time horizon.

**Complement 1:** 1+1D code

```
source[x_, t_] = 
  3 BSplineBasis[3, t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4] +
   2 BSplineBasis[3, -2 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 5/8) 4] +
   BSplineBasis[3, -1 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 2/8) 4] +
   BSplineBasis[3, -1 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4] +
   BSplineBasis[3, -1/2 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 4/8) 4] +
   3/2 BSplineBasis[3, -3 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4];
sol0 = NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, t], t] - 1/4 D[f[x, t], x, x] == 
     source[x, t],
    f[x, 0] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, 
   f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}];
nn = 16; knots = Flatten[{{0, 0}, (Range[0, nn]/nn), {1, 1}}];
basis0 = Flatten@
   Table[BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, 
      t], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];
basis = Flatten@
   Table[NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, t], t] - 1/4 D[f[x, t], x, x] == 
       BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, t],
      f[x, 0] == 0, f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, 
     f[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}];
data = N[Flatten[
    Table[{x, t, sol0[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/32}, {t, 0, 1, 1/32}], 1]];
data0 = N[
   Flatten[Table[{x, t, source[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/32}, {t, 0, 1, 
      1/32}], 1]];
ff = Function[{x, t}, basis0 // Evaluate];
a0 = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data0);
ff = Function[{x, t}, basis // Evaluate];
a = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data);
fit0[x_, t_] = 
  basis0.LinearSolve[Transpose[a0].a0, 
    Transpose[a0].(Last /@ data0)];
fit[x_, t_] = 
  basis.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)];
ff = Function[{x, t}, D[basis0, x, x] + D[basis0, t, t] // Evaluate];
s0 = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data0);
pen = Transpose[s0].s0; pen /= Max[Flatten[Abs[pen]]];
sol[x_, t_] = 
  basis0.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a + 10^-7 pen, 
    Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)];
ContourPlot[source[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All,Exclusions -> None]
ContourPlot[sol[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

**Complement 2**: 2+1D codes

For the sake of completeness and to demonstrate why a more 
efficient implementation is needed here is the code for 2D
diffusion without FEM (which for n=16 would take a white to run!).

```
source[x_, y_, t_] = BSplineBasis[3, t ] BSplineBasis[3, x]*
  BSplineBasis[3, y]  
sol0 = NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, y, t], t] - 1/4 D[f[x, y, t], x, x] - 
     1/4 D[f[x, y, t], y, y] == source[x, y, t], f[x, y, 0] == 0,
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y, t] == 0, True]}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
nn = 2;knots = Flatten[{{0, 0}, (Range[0, nn]/nn), {1, 1}}];
basis0 = Flatten@
   Table[BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, y]
     BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, k, t], {i, 0, nn}, {j, 0, nn}, {k, 0, nn}];
basis = Flatten@(Table[
      ParallelTable[
       NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, y, t], t] - 1/4 D[f[x, y, t], x, x] - 
           1/4 D[f[x, y, t], y, y] == 
          BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, i, x] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, j, 
            y] BSplineBasis[{3, knots}, k, t], f[x, y, 0] == 0,
         DirichletCondition[f[x, y, t] == 0, True]}, 
        f[x, y, t], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}], {j, 0, nn}, {k, 
        0, nn}], {i, 0, nn}]);
  data0 = N[Flatten[Table[{x, y, t, source[x, y, t]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/nn/2}, 
           {y, 0,1, 1/nn/2}, {t, 0, 1, 1/nn/2}], 2]];
data = N[Flatten[
    Table[{x, y, t, sol0[x, y, t]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/nn/2}, {y, 0, 1, 
      1/nn/2}, {t, 0, 1, 1/nn/2}], 2]];
ff = Function[{x, y, t}, basis // Evaluate];
a = ParallelMap[ff @@ # &, Most /@ data];
ff = Function[{x, y, t}, D[basis0, x, x] +
 D[basis0, y, y] + D[basis0, t, t] // Evaluate];
s0 = ff @@ # & /@ (Most /@ data0);
pen = Transpose[s0].s0; pen /= Max[Flatten[Abs[pen]]];
sol[x_, y_, t_] = 
  basis0.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a + 10^-9 pen, 
    Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)];
ContourPlot[sol[x, 1/2, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, Contours -> 20, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

**Complement 3: Background**

Let

$$\mathcal{L}\psi = \rho  $$

represent a (linear) partial differential equation (possibly time dependant). 
I will assume that there exist [a basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method)
over which I can project $\psi$, so that 
$$ \psi(x)=\sum_n a_n \phi_n(x)\,,$$ where I also request that all $\phi_n(x)$ satisfy the boundary conditions of the partial differential equation
( $x$ can represent say $\mathbf{r}$ or $(\mathbf{r},t)$), i.e. the analysis is not necessary limited to stationary PDE).
If I put this expansion into the PDE, multiply by $\phi_p(x)$ (or a Dirac function as a variant, see below) and integrate over $x$, I get formally 
$$ \mathbf{L}\cdot \mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{P}\,, $$
where  $L_{ij}= \int d x \phi_i \mathcal{L} \phi_j  $,
$P_{i}= \int d x \phi_i \rho  $ and ${\Phi}_i= a_i$.

I can then invert for $ \mathbf{\Phi}$ as 
$$ \mathbf{\Phi} =\mathbf{L}^{(-1)} \cdot\mathbf{P}\,, $$
where $\mathbf{L}^{(-1)}$ is the (possibly regularised) pseudo inverse of $\mathbf L$ (e.g. through least square). This is a possible method for solving PDEs. I am assuming (wrongly?) that linear FEM methods are a variant of this technique.

Conversely, If I start with the solved equation

$$\psi = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho \,. $$ 
I can expand $\rho$ over a basis function,$\rho=\sum_n a_n \rho_n$ , project as previously and write eventually

$$ \mathbf{P} =\mathbf{R}^{(-1)}\cdot \mathbf{\Phi}\,, $$
where $\mathbf{R}^{(-1)}$ is the (possibly regularised) pseudo inverse of $\mathbf R$, whose components are $R_{ij}= \int d x \rho_i \mathcal{L}^{-1} \rho_j  $. 
In my code above I have implemented something closely related to the second method, relying on `NDSolve`  (I use a Dirac function instead of $ \rho_i$ 
to simply sample the measured $\phi(x)$). The reason is I am after 
recovering the source $\mathbf P$ given some knowledge of the response $\mathbf \Phi$.

> My hope is that since FEM method solve the first problem they should have *in store* the tools to solve the second problem more efficiently?

Comment: Oh finally here comes a serious question about inverse problem! I know little about the underlying theory, but am eager to learn something from the (possibly) upcoming answer(s)!

Comment: @xzczd If you are interested in inverse pbs I strongly recommend the web page of the late Albert Tarantola http://www.ipgp.jussieu.fr/%7Etarantola/

Comment: Personally I learnt from that paper http://www.ipgp.jussieu.fr/%7Etarantola/Files/Professional/Papers_PDF/GeneralizedNonlinear_latex.pdf

Comment: While I am interested I am not sure I understand the question. You want to write the above code with low level functions, in order to minimize computational time? I can certainly help in getting a low level FEM code of the ground but I am no expert in inverse problems. Some questions: What is the purpose of `a0` it does not seem to be used. Also your "complement" code misses a definition of `s0`. Have you had a look at the FEM programming tutorial?

Comment: Can you also add what `data0` is and probably remove or add `ShowProgress`. Perhaps it is better to start with `nn=2` to get to a working code.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. getting from 1+1D to 2/3+1D in the low level code is not  a big deal.

Comment: @chris, I don't know how to do it. Sorry.

Comment: @chris, not entirely, I must admit. My feeling is that this is project that would require more thought and time on my side to fully understand. A commitment which I do not want to make right now. Sorry about that.

Comment: I have to say that this question is way too broad. While the overarching concept of Tikhonov regularization is easy to explain, the algorithmic part is just not trivial. It really depends on the employed PDE and on what kind of data the measurements $\phi$ and parameters $\rho$ are.

Comment: For the heat equation in which $\rho$ is initial data and $\phi$ is rather late data of the solution, one can for example employ low rank approximation techniques such as POD (proper orthogonal decomposition) to speed up the forward operator and its adjoint (_both_ are required to solve inverse problem). This is possible because the solution operator of the heat equation is very forgetfull about the initial condition, so that its singular values decay very rapidly. This is btw. also the reason why inverting it is so error prone.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I can't disagree with you. The broadness is part of the motivation! It also reflects my very wide ignorance of FEM. Would you be able to identify in user21's answer which matrix correspond to the regularisation? I am naively assuming that NDSolve makes a choice of Tikhonov   regularisation and that I can inherit it?

Comment: There is quite some extensive literature on this topic in the optimal control community, though. I also like to mention that you probably want to use an $L^1$-regularization because your prior is probably that the sources are sparse (linear combinations of few Dirac measures) and the $L^1$-regularization is exactly the right tool to promote sparsity.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes I agree with the $L^1$ point. But I was even considering $\sum_i a_i^2$ out of a better choice that I know how to implement.

Comment: "Would you be able to identify in user21's answer which matrix correspond to the regularisation?" No, because user21'2 answer was not at all about the regularization if I read correctly.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher just to be clear I am not trying to write an inverter from scratch for arbitrary PDEs I am trying to connect inversion to the existing FEM package that user21 has developed. I still lack some form of regularisation matrix, but I was initially happy (as a first step) with the answer I was able to write below? If my interest is broadly shared this kind of tools might be part of mathematica 14 :-)

Comment: Maybe this paper http://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/mcrf.2020018 might give yiu an overview. Most important there is the literature list, in particular all the works by Casas, Clason, and Kunisch (in all possible combinations). The $L^2$-regularization is discussed in https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/120872395.

Comment: However, there is a reason why only 1D examples are discussed: The algorithmic part for higher dimensions is just very tough because one has to solve linear equations in $m \cdot n$ variables where $n$ is the number of spatial points and $m$ is _the exorbitantly high number of time steps_ in the PDE's discretization. One just cannot do that with direct linear solvers anymore and iterative solvers qould require preconditioners whose setup would be far from trivial.

Comment: "kind of tools might be part of mathematica 14" That is absolutely out of reach.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I wrote a paper about L1-L2 penalty  https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9808197.pdf but it assumed regular sampling. I would be very happy to see the simplest example you could answer  and use it as a starting point for my own sake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Henrik Schumacher's [great help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218473/1089) in extracting linear piecewise elements from FEM, let me provide a 1-spline solution appropriate for [April's fool day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day#April_fish).

[image]

**2D case**

Let us start with a fish implicit equation.

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(2 x^2 + y^2)^2 - 2 Sqrt[1] x ( 2 x^2 - 3 y^2) + 2 (y^2 - x^2)<= 0, {x, y}]
```

and discretise it

```
R = ToElementMesh[R0=DiscretizeRegion[reg], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.015, 
"MeshOrder" -> 1, MeshQualityGoal ->1]; R0
```

[image]

```
pts = R["Coordinates"]; n = Length[pts];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[
     {"DependentVariables","Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {R}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd,"DiffusionCoefficients" ->
      {{-IdentityMatrix[1]}}, "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
```

Discretisation yields

```
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
stiffness = dpde["StiffnessMatrix"];
mass = dpde["MassMatrix"];
```

To see how it works, let us  excite one basis element close to coordinate (0.4,0.1)

```
i = Nearest[pts -> "Index", {0.4, 0.1}][[2]];
hatfun = ConstantArray[0., n];hatfun[[i]] = 1.;
```

This is how to interpolate it.

```
hatfuninterpolated = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, hatfun];
plot1 = Plot3D[hatfuninterpolated[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R, 
  NormalsFunction -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

In order to compute the corresponding  potential let us extract the systemmatrix

```
bndplist = 
  Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[R["BoundaryElements"][[All, 1]]]];
intplist = Complement[Range[n], bndplist];
```

This is what `DeployBoundaryConditions` does to the stiffness matrix

```
systemmatrix = stiffness;
systemmatrix[[bndplist]] = 
  IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray, 
    WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision][[bndplist]];
```

Factorizing the system matrix:

```
S = LinearSolve[systemmatrix, Method -> "Pardiso"];
load = mass.hatfun;
```

Solving the actual equation yields the potential for this basis element.

```
solution = S[load];
solutioninterpolated = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, solution];
plot1 = Plot3D[solutioninterpolated[x, y] // Evaluate, 
 {x, y} \[Element] R,NormalsFunction -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[1 - z/2, 1 - z, 1/2 - z]], 
  PlotTheme -> "Business", BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Let us now define a basis function

```
basis0 = Table[
   hatfun = ConstantArray[0., n];
   hatfun[[i]] = 1;
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, hatfun],
   {i, 1, n}];
```

and compute its image

```
basis = Table[hatfun = ConstantArray[0., n];
   hatfun[[i]] = 1; load = mass.hatfun;solution = S[load];
  ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, solution],
   {i, 1, n}];
```

Let us now pick a set of points on our fish

```
data0 = RandomPoint[R0, 1500] // Sort;
ListPlot[data0]
```

[image]

and define a 'measured potential' from an (ad hoc random) set of 50 basis elements

```
hatfun0 = ConstantArray[0., n];
hatfun0[[RandomChoice[Range[n], 50]]] = 1;
load = mass.hatfun0;
solution = S[load];
sol0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, solution];
data = Map[{#[[2]], #[[1]], sol0[#[[2]], #[[1]]]} &, data0];
```

The linear model relating the basis to the data reads

```
ff = Function[{x, y}, Map[#[x, y] &, basis] // Evaluate];
a = Map[ff @@ # &, Most /@ data];

Clear[fit];
fit[x_, y_] := Module[{vec = Map[#[x, y] &, basis]},
   vec.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)]];
```

Let us  plot the fit:

```
Plot3D[fit[x, y] // Evaluate, {x, y} \[Element] R, 
 NormalsFunction -> None, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[1 - z/2, 1 - z, 1/2 - z]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

We can now also invert it:

```
Clear[inv];
inv[x_, y_] := Module[{vec = Map[#[x, y] &, basis0]},
   vec.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)]];
Plot3D[inv[x, y] // Evaluate, {x, y} \[Element] R, 
 NormalsFunction -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
 RGBColor[1 - z/2, 1 - z, 1/2 - z]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", PlotPoints -> 50, BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

It compares well with the input model:

```
hatfuninterpolated = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, hatfun0];
plot1 = Plot3D[hatfuninterpolated[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] R, 
  NormalsFunction -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  BoxRatios -> {2, 1, 1},
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

> **Caveat**: this is most likely not as efficient  as it should be (see Henrik's [comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218473/1089)). I could imagine e.g. that the  way the basis function is defined is probably in part redundant w.r.t. to what is available within the FEM toolbox.

But it does illustrate that we can invert a given PDE with arbitrary sampling and  ad hoc boundary  condition on a set of linear piecewise basis function, which is differentiable, which is pretty cool IMHO. This [question/answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218309/1089) provides means of regularising the inversion should this be needed
(i.e. if `a` is poorly conditioned, with very small eigenvalues).

**3D case**

Let us give in one block  the 3D code on a unit ball:

```
R = ToElementMesh[R0 = Ball[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.125/16, 
AccuracyGoal -> 1, "MeshOrder" -> 1];pts = R["Coordinates"];n = Length[pts];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", 
     "Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y, z}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {R}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
   "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-IdentityMatrix[3]}}, 
   "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}];
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd];
stiffness = dpde["StiffnessMatrix"];
mass = dpde["MassMatrix"];
bndplist = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[R["BoundaryElements"][[All, 1]]]];
intplist = Complement[Range[n], bndplist]; systemmatrix = stiffness;
systemmatrix[[bndplist]] = 
  IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray, 
    WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision][[bndplist]];
S = LinearSolve[systemmatrix, Method -> "Pardiso"];
   basis0 = Table[
   hatfun = ConstantArray[0., n];
   hatfun[[i]] = 1;
   ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, hatfun],
   {i, 1, n}];
   basis = Table[
   hatfun = ConstantArray[0., n];
   hatfun[[i]] = 1; load = mass.hatfun;
   solution = S[load];
   solutioninterpolated = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, solution];
   solutioninterpolated,
   {i, 1, n}];

data0 = RandomPoint[R0, 500] // Sort;    
hatfun0 = ConstantArray[0., n];
hatfun0[[RandomChoice[Range[n], 50]]] = 1;
load = mass.hatfun0; solution = S[load];
sol0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, solution];

data = Map[{#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]],sol0[#[[1]], #[[2]],#[[3]]]} &, data0];
ff = Function[{x, y, z}, Map[#[x, y, z] &, basis] // Evaluate];
a = Map[ff @@ # &, Most /@ data];   
Clear[fit];
fit[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{vec = Map[#[x, y, z] &, basis]},
   vec.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)]];  
Clear[inv];
inv[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{vec = Map[#[x, y, z] &, basis0]},
   vec.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)]];
```

As a check let us look at the cross section through the mid-plane 
of the inverted density and the input density resp.

```
Plot3D[inv[x, y, 0] // Evaluate, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
 NormalsFunction -> None, ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[1 - z/2, 1 - z, 1/2 - z]], 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", PlotPoints -> 50, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

```
hatfuninterpolated = ElementMeshInterpolation[{R}, hatfun0];
plot1 = Plot3D[hatfuninterpolated[x, y, 0], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
  NormalsFunction -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

[image]

It seems to work fine!

Answer (score 9):

I am going to show how to write this part of your post

```
source[t_, x_] = 
  3 BSplineBasis[3, t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4] + 
   2 BSplineBasis[3, -2 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 5/8) 4] + 
   BSplineBasis[3, -1 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 2/8) 4] + 
   BSplineBasis[3, -1 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4] + 
   BSplineBasis[3, -1/2 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 4/8) 4] + 
   3/2 BSplineBasis[3, -3 + t 4] BSplineBasis[3, (x - 1/8) 4];

tEnd = 2;
AbsoluteTiming[
 sol0 = NDSolveValue[{D[f[t, x], t] - 1/4 D[f[t, x], x, x] == 
      source[t, x], f[0, x] == 0, f[t, 0] == 0, f[t, 1] == 0}, 
    f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tEnd}
    , Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}
    ];]
(* {0.337181, Null} *)
```

with the low level FEM functions. It's still not quite clear to me how you want to make use of this. More on this later. Note that I added a method option to tell NDSolve to actually make use of the FEM. Not all of the NDSolve calls you show actually make use of the FEM. But I think the method used is also not relevant.

To understand the code that follows I'd advise to read the [FEMProgramming tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#509267359).

Set up the region, bcs, ics:

```
region = Line[{{0}, {1}}];
bcs = {DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, True]};
initialConditionValue = 0.;
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables" -> {u}, 
    "Space" -> {x}, "Time" -> t}];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
nr = ToNumericalRegion[region];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr, "Time" -> 0.}];
```

Set up the PDE coefficients without the load term:

```
dim = RegionDimension[region];
initCoeffs = 
  InitializePDECoefficients[vd, 
   sd, {"DampingCoefficients" -> {{1}}, 
    "DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{-1/4 IdentityMatrix[dim]}}}];
```

We omit the load term for now, as that is the term that is variable in your examples and we will take care of that later.

Initialize the BCs, method data and compute the stationary (time independent) discretization and boundary conditions of the PDE (without the load). These coefficients and discretizations are the same for all the PDEs you solve so we compute them only once.

```
initBCs = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {bcs}];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];

sdpde = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd, "Stationary"];
sbcs = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[initBCs, methodData, sd];
```

Now, we want to write a residual function for NDSolve to time integrate. At the same time we want the source to be variable.

```
makeResidualFunction[load_] := With[
  {loadCoeffs = 
    InitializePDECoefficients[vd, 
     sd, {"LoadCoefficients" -> {{load}}}]},
  With[
   {sloaddpde = 
     DiscretizePDE[loadCoeffs, methodData, sd, "Stationary"]},
   discretizePDEResidual[t_?NumericQ, u_?VectorQ, dudt_?VectorQ] := 
    Module[{l, s, d, m, tloaddpde},

     NDSolve`SetSolutionDataComponent[sd, "Time", t];
     NDSolve`SetSolutionDataComponent[sd, "DependentVariables", u];

     {l, s, d, m} = sdpde["SystemMatrices"];

     (* discretize and add the laod *)
     (*l+=sloaddpde["LoadVector"];*)
     tloaddpde = 
      DiscretizePDE[loadCoeffs, methodData, sd, "Transient"];
     l += tloaddpde["LoadVector"];

     DeployBoundaryConditions[{l, s, d}, sbcs];

     d.dudt + s.u - l
     ]
   ]
  ]
```

This functions get the 'source' function and defines a residual function.

Generate the initial conditions with boundary conditions deployed.

```
init = Table[
   initialConditionValue, {methodData["DegreesOfFreedom"]}];
init[[sbcs["DirichletRows"]]] = Flatten[sbcs["DirichletValues"]];
```

Get the sparsity pattern for the damping matrix for the time integration.

```
sparsity = sdpde["DampingMatrix"]["PatternArray"];
```

Set up the residual function.

```
makeResidualFunction[source[t, x]]
```

Do the time integration

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 ufun = NDSolveValue[{
    discretizePDEResidual[t, u[t], u'[ t]] == 0
    , u[0] == init}, u, {t, 0, tEnd}
   , Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
   , Jacobian -> {Automatic, Sparse -> sparsity}
   (*,EvaluationMonitor\[RuleDelayed](monitor=Row[{"t = ",CForm[t]}])*)
   , AccuracyGoal -> $MachinePrecision/4, 
   PrecisionGoal -> $MachinePrecision/4
   ]
 ]

(* {0.429631,.... *)
```

As you see the time integration is somewhat slower from top level code.

Convert the result to an interpolating function:

```
ffun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{ufun["Coordinates"][[1]], 
   methodData["ElementMesh"]}, Partition[ufun["ValuesOnGrid"], 1]]
```

Check that this is on the same order as the `NDSolve` result.

```
Plot3D[sol0[t, x] - ffun[t, x], {t, 0, tEnd}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

**Discussion:**

I think you make an implicit assumption that is not correct. You assume that the matrix assembly process is the expensive part. But it's not. It's the actual time integration that you need to do many many times that is expensive. Precomputing the system matrices can probably save a little when the parallel computation is run but you can not make the time integration go away altogether.

Comment: thanks very much. Yes I did wonder about the time integration per basis element.

Answer (score 6):

Let me try and begin to answer my own  question, as it might inspire better answers. Here I will solve the Poisson equation as a test case using 0-splines.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg0 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];
mesh0 = ToElementMesh[reg0, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.025, AccuracyGoal -> 1]
```

I can then extract the mesh elements

```
idx = mesh0["MeshElements"][[1, 1]];mesh0["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In order to define the density on each cell I need to find the convex hull of each cell

```
pol = Table[mesh0["Coordinates"][[ idx[[i]]]] // ConvexHullMesh, {i,Length[idx]}];
```

I can then use the function `RegionMember` to define the Indicator of that cell (as shown in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/217187/1089))

```
basis = Table[f[x_, y_] = Boole[ RegionMember[pol[[i]], {x, y}]]; 
   NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y] 
      + NeumannValue[0, True] // Evaluate,DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0],{i, Length[idx]}];
```

Then I can plot the basis

```
Plot3D[basis[[;; ;; 5]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Mesh"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course the main point of using the mesh of the FEM is that it can be non trivial. For instance

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh0 = ToElementMesh[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]], 
MaxCellMeasure -> 0.25, AccuracyGoal -> 1]; mesh0["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

while the same code will work exactly unchanged

```
pol = Table[mesh0["Coordinates"][[ idx[[i]]]] // ConvexHullMesh, {i,Length[idx]}];  
basis = Table[f[x_, y_] = Boole[ RegionMember[pol[[i]], {x, y}]]; 
   NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f[x, y] + 
        NeumannValue[0, True] // Evaluate,
     DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
    u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0],{i, Length[idx]}];
```

And once again

```
Plot3D[basis[[;; ;; 5]], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Mesh"]
```

Now the inverse problem is quite simple

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> I find the FEM toolkit extremely useful in this context because building  a basis function for non trivial geometry is ... non trivial, while the FEM package takes care of it all here.

This solution does **not** fully address my original question because the basis are 0-splines. Ideally cubic spline would be good too.

**Proof of concept for inversion**

Let's see how the basis can be used to fit some model. Let us start with a basis on the mesh

```
basis0 = Table[Boole[ RegionMember[pol[[i]], {x, y}]], {i,Length[idx]}];
```

and some add hoc density

```
source[x_, y_] = basis0[[{150, 170, 125}]].{2, 4, 5};
 ContourPlot[source[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0, PlotPoints -> 75, 
 ContourShading -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

that we will try and recover with the 
corresponding potential:

```
sol0 = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 
      source[x, y] + NeumannValue[0, True] // Evaluate,
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},  u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh0];
Plot3D[sol0[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4],
  PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "ZMesh", PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let us sample this potential on a set of random points

```
data0 = RandomPoint[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]],500] // Sort;

ListPlot[data0, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and build the corresponding data set with the value of the potential  on those points

```
data = Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], sol0[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, data0];
```

Then the linear model follows from the knowledge of the data, `data` and the basis `basis`:

```
ff = Function[{x, y}, basis // Evaluate];
a = Map[ff @@ # &, Most /@ data];
a//Image//ImageAjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(looks a bit like the [matrix](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The.Matrix.glmatrix.2.png)) and we can fit the data as

```
fit[x_, y_] = basis.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)];
```

which is a pretty good fit!

```
Plot3D[fit[x, y] - sol0[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly we can invert for the source density

```
inv[x_, y_] =basis0.LinearSolve[Transpose[a].a, Transpose[a].(Last /@ data)];
Plot3D[inv[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh0, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotTheme -> "ZMesh", PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course this inversion  is a bit of an overkill to just get the density from the known potential BUT the framework works for  any boundary condition and any sampling and arbitrary PDEs that mathematica can solve using FEM.

Indeed, compared to the analytic B-spline method, no extra work in needed to 
match the boundary conditions since the Mesh generator and FEM package takes care of that.

It is also worth pointing out that once `a` is known any data set can be inverted 
almost instantaneously.

**To Do**

1. I would be best to be able to define cubic splines as well on the mesh (following e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10997/1089)).
2. One needs to write regularisation matrices on the mesh as well, in order to be able to invert ill-conditioned problems (but see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218258/1089)).

Comment: @xzczd this is what I had in mind. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: You could use your code from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218309/18437) to speed up the `NDSolve` call here. You'd need to make a new coefficient that contains just the "LoadCoefficients" and re-use the stiffness matrix as that is the same in all cases. You possibly could even call `LinrearSolve[stiffness, Method->"Pardiso"]` once and apply that to each new right hand side. That will be very efficient. Keep going I am curious to see the result. It seems you are getting there.

Comment: @user21 thanks. I see your point in using the same stiffness matrix. Would you know how to get from the FEM framework the piece-wise linear basis (anchored on the vertices)  which would be the analogue of `basis0` above?  I guess this is related to this question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140601/1089

Comment: @user21 I used to know this 15 years ago: I even did this in 4D and 6D (phase space) in order to solve for Boltzmann's equation on 4-simplices. But it was fairly inelegant   and it would be much more useful to have an integrated solution like Mathematica's BSplineFunction

Comment: do you mean with shape functions like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/112937/18437)?