# Penalty function on discrete mesh using Laplace-Beltrami operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element-method, computational-geometry, mesh

**Context**

I am interested in extending to the ill-condionned regime the inversion of linear equations 
arising from inverting differential equations which have been solved via 0-splines over a mesh using 
the FEM toolkit in connection to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/216747/1089).

For this purpose I need to compute a discrete Laplacian operator on a given mesh produced by 
`ToElementMesh`.

**Question**

Given some mesh, and a discrete function associating a value at each mesh element, I would like to compute a penalty function corresponding to the integral of the Laplacian square of the  function over that mesh.

$$ P(\mathbf{a}) = \int \big|\Delta \phi \big|^2   dx\,, $$

where $\mathbf{a}=({a_i}_{i\le n})$ is a vector of values on the mesh elements
and $\phi(\mathbf{x})=\sum_i a_i \phi_i(\mathbf{x})$, with $\phi_i(\mathbf{x})=1$ iff $\mathbf{x}\in \mbox{cell}_i$ and $0$ otherwise.

Of course strictly speaking, as defined, $P$ is formally zero almost everywhere
since the functions $\phi_i$ are constant.

> What I am after is a Sparse matrix, $\cal D$,  so that

$$P(\mathbf{a}) = \mathbf{a}^T\cdot \cal D \cdot \mathbf{a}. $$

I am fairly sure some element of the answer is available in the [amazing answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603/1089) involving  the  [Laplace-Beltrami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) operator.

It would be best if the answer would work with meshes in dimension 2 and 3.

**Attempt**

I have implemented a test case.

```
 mesh0 = ToElementMesh[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.125, AccuracyGoal -> 2]
 mesh0["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From the mesh I can find their centroid

```
idx = mesh0["MeshElements"][[1, 1]];
tt = Table[mesh0["Coordinates"][[ idx[[i]]]], {i, Length[idx]}];
center = Map[1/Length[#] Plus @@ # &, tt, {1}];
ListPlot[center, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can then compute the matrix of distances between centroids of the mesh elements

```
 dist = DistanceMatrix[center];
```

If my mesh was regular I could use

```
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> -1, {i_, j_} /; i - j == 1 -> 
      2, {i_, j_} /; i - j == 2 -> -1}, {17, 15}] // Transpose;
s1 = ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[s, s]];
pen = Transpose[s1].s1; pen // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So an alternative is to compute difference of values at 3 centres, $2x_i -x_{i-1}-x_{i+1}$ and divide 
by the distance square between those centres as a discrete proxy for the Laplacian.

```
dif = SparseArray[{{nn, nn} -> 1,
    {1, 1} -> 1, {i_, i_} -> 
     2, {i_, j_} /; i - j == 1 -> -1, {i_, j_} /; 
      i - j == -1 -> -1}, {nn, nn}];
idist = Inverse@DistanceMatrix[center] // SparseArray;
idist = Transpose[idist]. idiot;
pen = Transpose[idist.dif].(idist.dif); pen // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This operator has the good taste to nul a constant vector, but it is 
expansive to compute. May be a workaround with `Nearest` is in order
to make idist sparse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @HenrikSchumacher's and @user21's advice,  I have extracted from the FEM tutorial a computation of stiffness matrix on the mesh as follows

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]], 
       MaxCellMeasure -> 0.125, AccuracyGoal -> 1, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
 nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
coefficients={"DiffusionCoefficients"->{{IdentityMatrix[2]}},"LoadCoefficients"->{{1}}};
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables" -> {u},"Space" -> {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr}];
initCoeffs = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, coefficients];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
finiteElements=DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs,methodData, sd,"SaveFiniteElements" -> True];
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = discretePDE["SystemMatrices"];
```

Then

```
    stiffness // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is (hopefully!) a matrix which applies a Laplacian to the coefficients of the  (piecewise linear) 1-spline evaluated on the vertices of the mesh.

Nicely, the method **works for 3D meshes** as well

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ball[],MaxCellMeasure->0.125/8,AccuracyGoal->1, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
Show[{mesh["Wireframe"],  mesh["Coordinates"] // 
   ListPointPlot3D[#, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10],
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RGBColor[x, y, z]]] &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[mesh];
coefficients = {"DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{IdentityMatrix[3]}}, 
   "LoadCoefficients" -> {{1}}};
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables" -> {u}, 
    "Space" -> {x, y, z}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space" -> nr}];
initCoeffs = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, coefficients];
methodData = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];
finiteElements=DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd,"SaveFiniteElements" -> True];
discretePDE = DiscretizePDE[initCoeffs, methodData, sd];
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = discretePDE["SystemMatrices"];
stiffness // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

If you insist on using my code from [the other post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172603/38178), this can be done as follows; note that you have to settle with first order FEM in that case:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

mesh0 = ToElementMesh[RegionUnion[Disk[], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 2}]],
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.125, AccuracyGoal -> 2, "MeshOrder" -> 1]
pts = mesh0["Coordinates"];
faces = mesh0["MeshElements"][[1, 1]];
pat = Partition[Flatten[getSurfaceLaplacianCombinatorics[faces]], 2];
flist = Flatten[faces];
laplacian = SurfaceLaplaceBeltrami[pts, flist, pat];
mass = SurfaceMassMatrix[pts, flist, pat];
lumpedmass = Total[mass];
invlumpedmass = 
  SparseArray[
    Partition[Union @@ mesh0["BoundaryElements"][[1, 1]], 1] -> 0., 
    Length[mass], 1.]/Total[mass];
bilaplacian = laplacian.(invlumpedmass laplacian);
```

Then the matrix `bilaplacian` is a somewhat crude approximation to what you are looking for. It is crude because it uses nonconforming (first order) finite elements and because it uses mass lumping. But it should be quite fast because of this (inverting the mass matrix `mass` would lead to a dense matrix).
You only require it as a regularizer, so this should work out well.

In general, you can use the stiffness matrix `laplacian` and the mass matrix `mass` provided by any other FEM tool (e.g., you can obtain them from the low level FEM tools in *Mathematica*, too). The only other ingredient would be a diagonal matrix `A` with ones on the diagonal for interior degrees of freedom and zeroes for the boundary degrees of freedom. Then the matrix that you seek should be

```
bilaplacian = laplacian.A.Inverse[mass].A.laplacian
```

Typically, `Inverse[mass]` is a dense matrix, so one should avoid inverting `mass` if possible. With first order FEM, one can employ mass lumping (as I did above). From what I heard, mass lumping does not work well for higher order FEM (but I could be wrong).
Hence I would suggest *Mathematica* first order low level FEM tools for the 3D case. For the 2D case with a planar mesh, it is up to you which one you want to use. I do not know whether *Mathematica* supports surface FEM in version 12.1; it does not in version 12. So if you want to use that for surfaces, you are doomed to use my code, I guess. ;)

Comment: Not more efficient, but more accurate in sense of convergence under mesh refinement. What I tried to say is that you can obtain `laplacian` and `mass` also as the stiffness matrix and mass matrix of any other FEM tool. (I am about to write that into the post...)

Comment: The dimension of `bilaplacian` is `{Length[pts], Length[pts]}`, no? Beware that I use `"MeshOrder" -> 1` to define `mesh0`.

Comment: I have to cerrect myself: You can start with the second `Block` in the relevant code block; everything before that is only relevant for curves.

Comment: Ah, I see. You meant to let your functions live on cells? Mine live on vertices (piecewise linear functions). And using piecewise constant functions would even more a variational crime as the one that I already commit by using piecewise linear functions... ;)

Comment: Thank you again for your swift reply. I ll try and see how I can project the vertices to the faces.

Comment: I don't think so. But honestly, I do not understand why You want to put the function values onto the cells. FEM also does not do that.

Comment: because I have defined by basis to be 0-Bsplines. I would be happy to define the basis as 1-Splines as well. I just don't know how to do this.